# How do I stop active menu items dragging whole array on selection

Tags: html, css, menu, click

I have a menu bar designed for mobile screens.

I am trying to format it so that when you 'click' an image it drops 3 pixels to indicate its selection - however the code I'm using drops the entire bar of images.

Here is the code:

```
#menubar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
.touch_nav {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
}
.touch_nav:active {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#navhome {
  background: url('./img/mobile/homebutton.png')
}
#navabout {
  background: url('./img/mobile/aboutbutton.png')
}
#navservices {
  background: url('./img/mobile/servicesbutton.png')
}
#navdownload {
  background: url('./img/mobile/downloadbutton.png')
}
#navenquiry {
  background: url('./img/mobile/enquirybutton.png')
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.touch_nav:active { 
    position:relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```

This will position the element relative to its current position without effecting any other elements.